# Can you declare facultative function arguments in Javascript?

Tags: php, javascript, function, default-value

Like you can in php

```
<?php
function whatever($var='') {

}
?>
```

can you do that in javascript?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In javascript you can call a function regardless of parameters.

In other words it's perfectly legal to declare a function like this:

```
 function func(par1, par3) {

   //do something
  }
```

and call it like this:

```
 func();
```

Comment: So is this "yes, you can set a default value", or "no, you cannot set a default value" ?

Comment: I phrased it wrong, what I meant was that can you add parameters without them having to be defined. And the answer is yes, you can. Unlike PHP.

Answer (score 12):

If you want to set a 'default' value to your arguments, you can do something like this:

```
function whatever(arg1) {
  arg1 = arg1 || 'default value';
}
```

Keep in mind that the 'default value' will be set if arg1 contains any *falsy*  value, like `null`, `undefined`, `0`, `false`, `NaN` or a zero-length string `""`.

Also in JavaScript functions you have the [`arguments`](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Functions_and_function_scope/arguments) object, it's an array-like object that contains the arguments passed to a function, therefore you can even declare a function without input arguments, and when you call it, you can pass some to it:

```
function whatever() {
  var arg1 = arguments[0];
}

whatever('foo');
```

*Edit:* For setting a default value only if it is truly undefined, as [@bobbymcr](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1449194/can-you-declare-facultative-function-arguments-in-javascript/1449211#1449211) comments, you could do something like this also:

```
function whatever(arg1) {
  arg1 = arg1 === undefined ? 'default value' : arg1;
}
```

Comment: See my answer for how to set default only if it is truly undefined.

Comment: @kangax: Oh yes, I missed NaN... adding it now... :)

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you can do this directly, but there are ways to achieve this.  Since JavaScript lets you omit parameters from a function call, you can check if a parameter is undefined and give it a default value if so:

```
function DoSomething(x, y, z)
{
    // set default values...

    if (typeof x == "undefined")
    {
        x = 5;
    }

    if (typeof y == "undefined")
    {
        y = "Hi";
    }

    if (typeof z == "undefined")
    {
        z = 3.14;
    }

    // ...
}
```

You can try calling it in the following ways to see the default values get assigned when the parameter is missing:

```
DoSomething();
DoSomething(4);
DoSomething(4, "X");
DoSomething(4, "X", 7.77);
```

Comment: Just to me I prefer x === undefined; 
To avoid typeof :)

Answer (score 0):

In JS by default arguments aren't required. For $arg = '' implementation you can use

```
function whatever(vars) {  
   vars = vars || 'default';  
   /* your code */    
}
```